# A Gronwall-type inequality

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, gronwall-type-inequality

I want to derive a Gronwall-type inequality from the inequality below. Here all the functions are nonnegative, continuous and if you need some assumptions you may use that.
$$ f^2(t) \leqslant g^2(t) + \int_0^t (f(s) +c) f(s) ds  \;\;\;\; (t \in [0,T]) $$
So please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $c >0$ then by the Young's inequality,
$$ \begin{eqnarray*} f^2 (t) &\leqslant& g^2 (t) + \int_0^t \bigg(f^2 (s) + \frac{c^2 + f^2 (s)}{2} \bigg) ds \\ & \leqslant & g^2 (t) + \frac{c^2}{2}T + \int_0^t \frac{3}{2}  f^2 (s) ds \end{eqnarray*}$$
So you can apply the Gronwall's inequality now.